# Deserialize XML Array into Object

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, deserialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to Deserialize a XML string into an object but it gives me the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException:   not expected.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp
    xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0      epp-1.0.xsd">
    <response>
        <result code="1000">
            <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
        </result>
        <trID>
            <svTRID>20151019181132-1C16AD22-396-0001</svTRID>
        </trID>
    </response>
</epp>
```

**CLASS:**

```
    Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable(), XmlRoot("epp")>
Public Class EPP

Public Sub New()
    Response = New Response()
End Sub

<XmlElement(ElementName:="response")> _
Public Property Response As Response
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class Response

Public Sub New()
    result = New result()
    trID = New trID()
End Sub

<XmlElement(ElementName:="result")> _
Public Property result As result

<XmlElement(ElementName:="trID")> _
Public Property trID As trID
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class trID

Public Sub New()
    svTRID = String.Empty
End Sub

<XmlElement(ElementName:="svTRID")> _
Public Property svTRID As String
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class result

Public Sub New()
    msg = String.Empty
End Sub

<XmlElement(ElementName:="msg")> _
Public Property msg As String
End Class
```

**Here is the code:**

```
Dim r As New EPP
Dim x As New XmlSerializer(r.GetType)

Using s As New StringReader(response.Xml)
    r = x.Deserialize(s)
End Using
```

Is there anything wrong with the "EPP" class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has a default [namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) of `"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"` so you need to indicate that your classes are to be serialized into this namespace.  The easiest way is to set [`<XmlRoot(Namespace := "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0")>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the root class, and [`<XmlType(Namespace := "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0")>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the remainder:

```
<XmlRoot("epp", Namespace := "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0")>
Public Class EPP
    Public Sub New()
        Response = New Response()
    End Sub

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="response")> _
    Public Property Response As Response
End Class

<XmlType(Namespace := "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0")>
Public Class Response

    Public Sub New()
        result = New result()
        trID = New trID()
    End Sub

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="result")> _
    Public Property result As result

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="trID")> _
    Public Property trID As trID
End Class

<XmlType(Namespace := "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0")>
Public Class trID
    Public Sub New()
        svTRID = String.Empty
    End Sub

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="svTRID")> _
    Public Property svTRID As String
End Class

<XmlType(Namespace := "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0")>
Public Class result

    Public Sub New()
        msg = String.Empty
    End Sub

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="msg")> _
    Public Property msg As String
End Class
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2zUUR).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!